# Gimbal Locking when projecting 3D System onto Sphere

Tags: opengl, vector, rotation, quaternions, skybox

I'm making a skybox in my game. The game has a solar system with some things in it (to start, the sun and the earth, with stars in the background). The player is on one planet in this solar system. The solar system is represented to the player using a skybox, with 2D sprites projected onto the skybox in the corresponding positions. The Skybox is rendered with OpenGL (actually, Java's LWJGL) [1]

First things first, all of the bodies are being tracked in 3D space. I can obtain their coordinates, relative directions, etc. All orbits are defined independently (aka, occur on arbitrary planes). In addition, planets have Quaternion rotations. Rendering the system in full 3D, there are no problems.

---

Projecting the system to the skybox is another matter entirely. In theory, I figure that I should be able to do it like this;

**1.** Calculate direction vector of where the player is looking (full rotations are not relevant - the vector just has to point in the right direction).

**2.** Multiply this direction vector with their planet's orientation (Quaternion) to calculate the "view direction"

**3.** Calculate direction vector from the planet to the object being viewed

**4.** Find the rotation between the vectors, and rotate the skybox accordingly.

---

However, when I feed OpenGL my angles, Gimbal Locking occurs and orbits that should be straight: go all bendy (although rotations around one single axis work fine). In what ways can I attempt to prevent this from happening? I'm at a loss.

*[1]: My terrain is actually a flat square voxel grid, and I scale the player's coordinates onto it, then pretend that it is a 3D planet.*